# Android RX Java, can not resolve scheduler.io()

Tags: android, rx-android

I am very new to Java, Android and RX Java.I am interested in implementing the Architectural components together with RX Java.

I have repository which makes a call to my API service to get the session id from the server. I am having problems in getting the data smoothly to my Repository where i wish to consume and store the data in room.

Retrofit interface:-

```
Observable<MainResponse> sendJsonLink1(@Query("svc")String svc, 
@Query("params")String params);
```

ApiService:

```
MtsApiInterface mtsApiInterface 
=RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(MtsApiInterface.class);

public Observable<MainResponse> GetSessionandResourceID(String svc, String 
params) {
    return mtsApiInterface.sendJsonLink1(svc, params);
}
```

Repository:

```
public MutableLiveData<String> getSessionId() {
    Observable<MainResponse> mainResponseObserver = 
mtsAPI.GetSessionandResourceID("token/login", AppConstants.PARAMS + "");
    mainResponseObserver.subscribeOn(Scheduler.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<MainResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(MainResponse mainResponse) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });

    return msessionId;

}
```

the above repository code does not work, it says can not resolve scheduler.io()....

I am stuck on last part. I don't know how to get the data in the repository and send it to the view model through live data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `Schedulers.io()` not `Scheduler.io()`

"Scheduler" with an 's'

From the documentation

> [Schedulers.io()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/schedulers/Schedulers.html#io%28%29)  - meant for I/O-bound work such as asynchronous
>   performance of blocking I/O, this scheduler is backed by a thread-pool
>   that will grow as needed; for ordinary computational work, switch to
>   Schedulers.computation( ); Schedulers.io( ) by default is a
>   CachedThreadScheduler, which is something like a new thread scheduler
>   with thread caching

Comment: Thanks... oops missed that... but Still doesnt work. it seems to not get the data as it misses the onNext Completely. Further more how to i send this data also if i get it from here to downstream to the ViewModel if i needed to

Comment: Did your code land into `onError()`? or did it even executed statements in `onSubscribe()`?

Comment: it gets to :- .subscribe(new Observer<MainResponse>() .. after this it skips completely  to return. No onError no nothing

Comment: It might be the problem with the API, did you check your Logs?

Comment: Yes there is no error nothing.. The api was tested before and is working..

Comment: Did you try printing the logs in all the 4 functions (onSubscribe, ..... , & onComplete)

Comment: oh its working........  Is this the correct way.. or is there a better way? Now how to i transfer the data got in onNext to the the Mutable live data so the view model can recieve it ?Thankss for the help

Comment: That's one of the ways to do that, and yes it is correct. "transfer the data got in onNext to the Mutable live data so the view model can receive it ". I am unaware of all that. I need more data, anyway please mark this answer as answered so it can help other users as well.